# Regex to validate an alphanumeric string with optional space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been working on a regex for validating an alphanumeric string with the rules as below:

1. The first **FOUR** starting characters must be numbers and last
   **TWO** characters must be alphabets.
2. The space is **OPTIONAL** but must be placed between two characters,
   meaning trailing space is not allowed.
3. The length of postal code must be **6 characters** if SPACE is
   **not included** and **7 characters** if space is **included**.

Eg.

- 1111 ZZ
- 111 1ZZ
- 1 111ZZ
- 1111ZZ

I tried using `^[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$|^(?=[\d|\D]+ [\d|\D]+).{7}$` but this also validates **9999 1A** as TRUE which should actually be FALSE.

Any leads or help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you can't remove all spaces (leading, middle or trailing), and still have the same semantic 'value'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=^.{6,7}$)^(([0-9] ?){4}( ?[a-zA-Z]){2})$
```

will match

- 1111 ZZ
- 111 1ZZ
- 1 111ZZ
- 1111ZZ
- 1111 ZZ

but not

- 9999 1A
- 11111 Z
- 1111111
- 11 11 ZZ

https://regex101.com/r/lByOx6/1

EDIT: explanation

The "Positive Lookahead" part:

- `(?=^.{6,7}$)` this only matches if the string meets the requirements, BUT it does not 'consume' the characters.

  - . is any character
  - {6,7} is about repetitions

so `(?=^.{6,7}$)` is matched if the string has 6 or 7 characters, no matter what

Then the following part already 'consumes' the string to say that I want at the start 4 repetitions of numbers and optionally space, and at the end 2 repetitions of letters and optionally space. The second part would accept strings such as `1 1 1 1  Z Z` but as those are more than 7 characters, the first part wouldn't let the string match.

Comment: Thanks! that solves the problem. Can you also explain a little bit how the regex is working? It will help :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest simplifying the problem ahead of time, by reducing all white spaces, which you seem to be uninterested in anyway:

```js
var candidate = input.replaceAll(/\s/mg, '');
```

Then the regex is simply: `/^\d{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$/`

If, however, you need to validate, that there actually are no leading or trailing white spaces, you can validate that ahead of time, and return a negative result right away.

Comment: Once you've removed the spaces, `[0-9A-Za-z]*` becomes wrong (it would ie validate "111111ZZ"), /^\d{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$/ is enough

Comment: @MaxXapi You are correct. I forgot about the '6 character' constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to check if the string contains an optional space between the first and the last non whitespace character.

Then match  the first digit followed by 3 digits separated by an optional space and 2 or 3 times a char a-zA-Z or a space.

Using a case insensitive match:

```
^(?=\S+ ?\S+$)\d(?: ?\d){3}[A-Z ]{2,3}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what on the right is

  - `\S+ ?\S+$` Match optional space between the first and the last non whitespace char
- `)`  Close lookahead
- `\d(?: ?\d){3}` Match a digit and repeat 3 times an optional space and a digit
- `[a-zA-Z ]{2,3}` Match 2-3 times either a char a-zA-Z or a space
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SAy6DY/1)